# Is it possible to add a symlink to a repository via TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, symlink

I'd like to add a symlink to an SVN repository via TortoiseSVN. SVN does support symlinks as "special" files, but Windows can't create POSIX symlinks. Is there some magical workaround? Would creating one through, e.g., cygwin do the trick?

Comment: Have you looked at svn:externals? svn:externals let you point one location in your repository at another, and you don't need to worry about using cygwin, plus the solution is platform independent.

Comment: svn:externals is designed to bring a, well, *external* repository into yours; not a different location in your own repository.

Comment: that may be what it's designed for, but it works equally well pointed at the *local* repository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a symlink in cygwin would work, but you would have to use a cygwin-compiled command-line `svn` tool to do the initial commit. TortoiseSVN wouldn't understand cygwin symlinks.

Comment: The Cygwin svn client works just fine. Once setup you can use both Cygwin and Tortoise to manage the same files.